# Protecting PowerPivot tables in Excel 2010 without SharePoint

Tags: excel, excel-2010, powerpivot, vba

Is there a way to protect tables in PowerPivot without going through SharePoint? I want the user to be able to manipulate the PivotTables created from the PowerPivot tables, but I don't want them to see the tables in PowerPivot. Without SharePoint, is it possible to disable the PowerPivot Window, change the execution mode or password protect the PowerPivot tables from view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lolatu, you can't unfortunately do that. If you import the data directly into the powerpivot window, they are not going to be visible in the client if you hide them, if the user fires up the powerpivot window, there is currently no workaround for that.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely possible. Follow below steps:

1. In Excel click on `Review` tab in ribbon bar;
2. Click on `Protect Workbook`;
3. Check 'Structure' and provide the password.
4. Now if you click on *Powerpivot -> Manage*, it will pop up a message saying `PowerPivot is protected`.

Enjoy :)